# how to find consecutive occurances of 1 with condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 code      tank     date         time       no_operation_flag
 123       1        01-01-2019   00:00:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   00:30:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   01:00:00   0
 123       1        01-01-2019   01:30:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   02:00:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   02:30:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   03:00:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   03:30:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   04:00:00   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   00:00:00   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   00:30:00   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   01:00:00   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   01:30:00   0
 123       2        01-01-2019   02:00:00   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   02:30:00   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   03:00:00   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   03:30:00   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   04:00:00   1
```

What I want to do is to flag consecutive 1's in `no_operation_flag` more than 3 times at tank level. Dataframe is already sorted at tank,date and time level.

```
 code      tank     date         time       no_operation_flag   final_flag
 123       1        01-01-2019   00:00:00   1                   0
 123       1        01-01-2019   00:30:00   1                   0
 123       1        01-01-2019   01:00:00   0                   0
 123       1        01-01-2019   01:30:00   1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   02:00:00   1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   02:30:00   1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   03:00:00   1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   03:30:00   1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   04:00:00   1                   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   00:00:00   1                   0
 123       2        01-01-2019   00:30:00   1                   0    
 123       2        01-01-2019   01:00:00   1                   0   
 123       2        01-01-2019   01:30:00   0                   0
 123       2        01-01-2019   02:00:00   1                   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   02:30:00   1                   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   03:00:00   1                   1
 123       2        01-01-2019   03:30:00   1                   1 
 123       2        01-01-2019   04:00:00   1                   1
```

How do I do it in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crete consecutive groups with [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html), not equal and cumulative sum, then get counts with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), compare with [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for `>` and `1` values, last set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
shifted = df.groupby(['code','tank'])['no_operation_flag'].shift()
g = df['no_operation_flag'].ne(shifted).cumsum()

mask = g.map(g.value_counts()).gt(3) & df['no_operation_flag'].eq(1)

df['no_operation_flag'] = np.where(mask, 1, 0)
```

Or:

```
df['no_operation_flag'] = mask.astype(int)

print (df)
    code  tank        date      time  no_operation_flag
0    123     1  01-01-2019  00:00:00                  0
1    123     1  01-01-2019  00:30:00                  0
2    123     1  01-01-2019  01:00:00                  0
3    123     1  01-01-2019  01:30:00                  1
4    123     1  01-01-2019  02:00:00                  1
5    123     1  01-01-2019  02:30:00                  1
6    123     1  01-01-2019  03:00:00                  1
7    123     1  01-01-2019  03:30:00                  1
8    123     1  01-01-2019  04:00:00                  1
9    123     2  01-01-2019  00:00:00                  0
10   123     2  01-01-2019  00:30:00                  0
11   123     2  01-01-2019  01:00:00                  0
12   123     2  01-01-2019  01:30:00                  0
13   123     2  01-01-2019  02:00:00                  1
14   123     2  01-01-2019  02:30:00                  1
15   123     2  01-01-2019  03:00:00                  1
16   123     2  01-01-2019  03:30:00                  1
17   123     2  01-01-2019  04:00:00                  1
```

Comment: How can we check consecutive time as well in above code?

Comment: @Neil - hmmm, do you think difference of time is same?

Comment: There may be some missing time buckets, so I need to check consecutive time buckets.

Comment: @Neil - hmm, is posible post new question? Because not sure if understand.

Comment: Yes, doing that

Comment: new question posted.