# how to find consecutive occurances of value with condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 code      tank     date         time       no_operation_flag
 123       1        01-01-2019   00:00:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   00:30:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   01:00:00   0
 123       1        01-01-2019   01:30:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   02:00:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   02:30:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   03:00:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   03:30:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   04:00:00   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   05:00:00   1                   
 123       1        01-01-2019   14:00:00   1                     
 123       1        01-01-2019   14:30:00   1                  
 123       1        01-01-2019   15:00:00   1                  
 123       1        01-01-2019   15:30:00   1                  
 123       1        01-01-2019   16:00:00   1                    
 123       1        01-01-2019   16:30:00   1                  
 123       2        02-01-2019   00:00:00   1
 123       2        02-01-2019   00:30:00   0
 123       2        02-01-2019   01:00:00   0
 123       2        02-01-2019   01:30:00   0
 123       2        02-01-2019   02:00:00   1
 123       2        02-01-2019   02:30:00   1
 123       2        02-01-2019   03:00:00   1
 123       2        03-01-2019   03:30:00   1
 123       2        03-01-2019   04:00:00   1
 123       1        03-01-2019   14:00:00   1
 123       2        03-01-2019   15:00:00   1
 123       2        03-01-2019   00:30:00   1
 123       2        04-01-2019   11:00:00   1
 123       2        04-01-2019   11:30:00   0
 123       2        04-01-2019   12:00:00   1
 123       2        04-01-2019   13:30:00   1
 123       2        05-01-2019   03:00:00   1
 123       2        05-01-2019   03:30:00   1
 123       2        05-01-2019   04:00:00   1
```

What I want to do is to flag consecutive 1's in `no_operation_flag` more than 5 times at tank level and day level, but the time should be consecutive (time is at half an hour level). Dataframe is already sorted at tank, date and time level.

My desired dataframe would be

```
 code       tank      date          time        no_operation_flag   final_flag
 123       1        01-01-2019   00:00:00       1                   0                   
 123       1        01-01-2019   00:30:00       1                   0
 123       1        01-01-2019   01:00:00       0                   0  
 123       1        01-01-2019   01:30:00       1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   02:00:00       1                   1  
 123       1        01-01-2019   02:30:00       1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   03:00:00       1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   03:30:00       1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   04:00:00       1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   05:00:00       1                   0
 123       1        01-01-2019   14:00:00       1                   1  
 123       1        01-01-2019   14:30:00       1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   15:00:00       1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   15:30:00       1                   1
 123       1        01-01-2019   16:00:00       1                   1  
 123       1        01-01-2019   16:30:00       1                   1
 123       2        02-01-2019   00:00:00       1                   0
 123       2        02-01-2019   00:30:00       0                   0    
 123       2        02-01-2019   01:00:00       0                   0
 123       2        02-01-2019   01:30:00       0                   0
 123       2        02-01-2019   02:00:00       1                   0
 123       2        02-01-2019   02:30:00       1                   0
 123       2        02-01-2019   03:00:00       1                   0
 123       2        03-01-2019   03:30:00       1                   0
 123       2        03-01-2019   04:00:00       1                   0
 123       1        03-01-2019   14:00:00       1                   0
 123       2        03-01-2019   15:00:00       1                   0
 123       2        03-01-2019   00:30:00       1                   0
 123       2        04-01-2019   11:00:00       1                   0
 123       2        04-01-2019   11:30:00       0                   0 
 123       2        04-01-2019   12:00:00       1                   0
 123       2        04-01-2019   13:30:00       1                   0
 123       2        05-01-2019   03:00:00       1                   0
 123       2        05-01-2019   03:30:00       1                   0 
 123       2        05-01-2019   04:00:00       1                   0
```

How can I do this in pandas?

Comment: Because it has no operation flag as 1 starting from 01:30 till 04:00

Comment: One thing - do you need first filter by consecutive datetimes and then in filtered data count 5 consecutive `True`s, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57886573/2901002), only filtering for consecutive datetimes per groups with new helper `DataFrame` with added all missing datetimes, last `merge` for add new column:

```
df['datetimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str))
df1 = (df.set_index('datetimes')
          .groupby(['code','tank', 'date'])['no_operation_flag']
          .resample('30T')
          .first()
          .reset_index())

shifted1 = df1.groupby(['code','tank', 'date'])['no_operation_flag'].shift()
g1 = df1['no_operation_flag'].ne(shifted1).cumsum()
mask1 = g1.map(g1.value_counts()).gt(5) & df1['no_operation_flag'].eq(1)

df1['final_flag'] = mask1.astype(int)
#print (df1.head(40))

df = df.merge(df1[['code','tank','datetimes','final_flag']]).drop('datetimes', axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
    code  tank        date      time  no_operation_flag  final_flag
0    123     1  01-01-2019  00:00:00                  1           0
1    123     1  01-01-2019  00:30:00                  1           0
2    123     1  01-01-2019  01:00:00                  0           0
3    123     1  01-01-2019  01:30:00                  1           1
4    123     1  01-01-2019  02:00:00                  1           1
5    123     1  01-01-2019  02:30:00                  1           1
6    123     1  01-01-2019  03:00:00                  1           1
7    123     1  01-01-2019  03:30:00                  1           1
8    123     1  01-01-2019  04:00:00                  1           1
9    123     1  01-01-2019  05:00:00                  1           0
10   123     1  01-01-2019  14:00:00                  1           1
11   123     1  01-01-2019  14:30:00                  1           1
12   123     1  01-01-2019  15:00:00                  1           1
13   123     1  01-01-2019  15:30:00                  1           1
14   123     1  01-01-2019  16:00:00                  1           1
15   123     1  01-01-2019  16:30:00                  1           1
16   123     2  02-01-2019  00:00:00                  1           0
17   123     2  02-01-2019  00:30:00                  0           0
18   123     2  02-01-2019  01:00:00                  0           0
19   123     2  02-01-2019  01:30:00                  0           0
20   123     2  02-01-2019  02:00:00                  1           0
21   123     2  02-01-2019  02:30:00                  1           0
22   123     2  02-01-2019  03:00:00                  1           0
23   123     2  03-01-2019  03:30:00                  1           0
24   123     2  03-01-2019  04:00:00                  1           0
25   123     1  03-01-2019  14:00:00                  1           0
26   123     2  03-01-2019  15:00:00                  1           0
27   123     2  03-01-2019  00:30:00                  1           0
28   123     2  04-01-2019  11:00:00                  1           0
29   123     2  04-01-2019  11:30:00                  0           0
30   123     2  04-01-2019  12:00:00                  1           0
31   123     2  04-01-2019  13:30:00                  1           0
32   123     2  05-01-2019  03:00:00                  1           0
33   123     2  05-01-2019  03:30:00                  1           0
34   123     2  05-01-2019  04:00:00                  1           0
```

Comment: I checked on my dataframe, but it does not seem to work with following scenario. e.g. following buckets has flag `1` 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00, 02:30, 03:00 , 04:00, 13:00,13:30,14:00,14:30,15:00,15:30. Its only flagging it in buckets from 00:30 till 03:00. It is not flagging in 13:00 till 15:30

Comment: @Neil - hmmm, so `00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00, 02:30, 03:00 , 04:00, 13:00,13:30,14:00,14:30,15:00,15:30` should be count like 2 consecutive groups - `00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00, 02:30, 03:00` and `04:00, 13:00,13:30,14:00,14:30,15:00,15:30` ?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I have updated the same in my question

Comment: @Neil - small bug, changed `shifted1 = df1.groupby(['code','tank'])['no_operation_flag'].shift()` to `shifted1 = df1.groupby(['code','tank', 'date'])['no_operation_flag'].shift()`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['final_flag'] = ( df.groupby([df['no_operation_flag'].ne(1).cumsum(),
                                 'tank',
                                 'date',
                                 pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str))
                                   .diff()
                                   .ne(pd.Timedelta(minutes = 30))
                                   .cumsum(),
                                'no_operation_flag'])['no_operation_flag']
                    .transform('size')
                    .gt(5)
                    .view('uint8') )
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    code  tank        date      time  no_operation_flag  final_flag
0    123     1  01-01-2019  00:00:00                  1           0
1    123     1  01-01-2019  00:30:00                  1           0
2    123     1  01-01-2019  01:00:00                  0           0
3    123     1  01-01-2019  01:30:00                  1           1
4    123     1  01-01-2019  02:00:00                  1           1
5    123     1  01-01-2019  02:30:00                  1           1
6    123     1  01-01-2019  03:00:00                  1           1
7    123     1  01-01-2019  03:30:00                  1           1
8    123     1  01-01-2019  04:00:00                  1           1
9    123     1  01-01-2019  05:00:00                  1           0
10   123     1  01-01-2019  14:00:00                  1           1
11   123     1  01-01-2019  14:30:00                  1           1
12   123     1  01-01-2019  15:00:00                  1           1
13   123     1  01-01-2019  15:30:00                  1           1
14   123     1  01-01-2019  16:00:00                  1           1
15   123     1  01-01-2019  16:30:00                  1           1
16   123     2  02-01-2019  00:00:00                  1           0
17   123     2  02-01-2019  00:30:00                  0           0
18   123     2  02-01-2019  01:00:00                  0           0
19   123     2  02-01-2019  01:30:00                  0           0
20   123     2  02-01-2019  02:00:00                  1           0
21   123     2  02-01-2019  02:30:00                  1           0
22   123     2  02-01-2019  03:00:00                  1           0
23   123     2  03-01-2019  03:30:00                  1           0
24   123     2  03-01-2019  04:00:00                  1           0
25   123     1  03-01-2019  14:00:00                  1           0
26   123     2  03-01-2019  15:00:00                  1           0
27   123     2  03-01-2019  00:30:00                  1           0
28   123     2  04-01-2019  11:00:00                  1           0
29   123     2  04-01-2019  11:30:00                  0           0
30   123     2  04-01-2019  12:00:00                  1           0
31   123     2  04-01-2019  13:30:00                  1           0
32   123     2  05-01-2019  03:00:00                  1           0
33   123     2  05-01-2019  03:30:00                  1           0
```

Comment: Do you use input data? I think not.

Comment: I saw that OP had changed the DataFrame for the expected output and decided to use that one so I could check the solution, check : `My desired dataframe would be:` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855887/how-to-find-consecutive-occurances-of-value-with-condition-in-python/59856244#59856231

Comment: difference is not count per groups, maybe necessary, maybe not...

Comment: @ansev getting following error `TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to do in one go but the two steps approach is simpler,
first you select tanks one by one and then you look for the sequence of five 1.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555031/pandas-find-sequence-or-pattern-in-column) already solves the searching the pattern in a column.

If you want to go the other way you might take a look at [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas.DataFrame.rolling), you can either sum the `1` or use a `all values are True` condition to find the sequence of `n` elements.

You could also just [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask) mask a column but that would give you just the values in the mask. This solves the other problem, "which tanks where non operative at a give time".

Answer (score 0):

This is very premitive and somewhat dirty way but easy to understand, I think.

1. For loop of rows, check time after 4 rows is 2 hours far.
2. (if 1 is True) Check all of corresponding five values of `df['no_operation_flag']` are 1.
3. (if 2 is True) Put 1 in corresponding five values of `df['final_flag']`.

---

```
# make col with zero
df['final_flag'] = 0

for i in range(1, len(df)-4):
    j = i + 4
    dt1 = df['date'].iloc[i]+' '+df['time'].iloc[i]
    ts1 = pd.to_datetime(dt1)
    dt2 = df['date'].iloc[j]+' '+df['time'].iloc[j]
    ts2 = pd.to_datetime(dt2)

    # timedelta is 2 hours?
    if ts2 - ts1 == datetime.timedelta(hours=2, minutes=0):
        # all of no_operation_flag == 1?
        if (df['no_operation_flag'].iloc[i:j+1] == 1).all():
            df['final_flag'].iloc[i:j+1] = 1
```